# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/router/index.js' does not provide an export name default

Tags: vuejs3

I am attempting to build a vue 3 with  and typescript website and am getting an error but can't figure out why.  The error I get is

**Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/router/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.js:6:8)**

Here's my main.js code:

```
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

import "@/index.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";   //<-- line 6
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";

import "primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
import "primevue/resources/primevue.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(createPinia());
app.use(router);
app.use(PrimeVue);

app.mount("#app");
```

For more context, here's my github [repo](https://github.com/ilatine/otg-website/tree/otg-v1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import { router } from "./router";   //<-- line 6
```

There are two primary ways to export values with JavaScript: default exports and named exports. So far, our examples have only used default exports. But you can use one or both of them in the same file. A file can have no more than one default export, but it can have as many named exports as you like.
[image]